# Chain multiple promises in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following structure and need to simplify it,

Resuable service1 to interact with IndexedDB

```
function isDbExist (){
// do something , it return either reject or resolve
}

function createDB (){
// do something , it return either reject or resolve
}

function getData (){
    // do something , it return either reject or resolve
}
```

In another service2 I'm injecting this service1 and using the functions as such

```
function1 (){
service1.isDbExist.then(function(data){
   service1.createDB.then(function(data){
      service1.getData.then(function(data){
        referred.resolve(data);
      },function(error){
       deferred.reject(error)
      })
   },function(error){
    deferred.reject(error);
   })
},function(error){
   deferred.reject(error);
})
}
```

The problem here is the readability of the code is not good, its not easy to debug as which reject function is for which promise. Is their some good way of doing this ? I have read about $q.all but don't this its applicable in this situation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Exactly, the beauty of promises is that you can chain them as opposed to nesting them like callbacks. You can return another promise when dealing with the previous like so:

```
isDbExists().then(function(db) {
  // do something
  return createDb();
}).then(function(db) {
  // do something with with the resolved db..
  return getData();
}).then(function(data) {
  // Do something with data
}).catch(function(error) {
  // Uh oh, something went wrong. Deal with error
});
```

Finally, you deal with the error that may have occurred.

Comment: can you explain why are you using return ?

Comment: Returning a promise within the `then()` allows you chain promises in this way

Comment: Because he's simply passing in the functions that return promises. Either approach is valid

Comment: Was just implementing this solution , came up one more problem. I need to call a async function if one of the promises fail , after that promise succeeds i need to continue the normal execution. If not clear i can make a fiddle

Answer (score 5):

You can chain multiple promises like this:

```
service1.isDbExist()
    .then(service1.createDB)
    .then(service1.getData)
    .then(function() {
        // DB exists, created and data loaded
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        console.log('Handle error', err); // isDbExist, createDB or getData rejected
    });
```

Check interactive demo to see how success and error data is passed to the next promise in chain and how you have full control over process on each step:

**Demo**: http://plnkr.co/edit/PM06e8NGJvHKmoJ9C2Lf?p=info

Comment: If the isDBExist is passing something in the resolve , how would i get that value in the .then(service1.createDB) ?

Comment: What I wrote is equivalent to `service1.isDbExist().then(function(data) { return service1.createDB(data); }).then(function(data) { return service1.getData(data); })..` so you don't have to worry about passing data to the next then in chain.

Comment: Yes, just worked , trying it out. Thanks. Will update you soon.

Comment: Thanks for the example, I have a couple of questions now,                               1. If isDbExist() is passing some data in resolve which needs to be passed to service1.createDB('pass something from isDBExist') , how to do this ?      2. The catch block only shows the error from the 1st promise , how to get the error data from other promises ?

Comment: Your first question is answered in mine below. As for the error, the .catch() will be called when the any of 3 promises are rejected

Comment: @Gaurav_soni Both you questions are demonstrated in the demo. *"The catch block only shows the error from the 1st promise"* - of course, because next promises are not going to be even invoked since previous failed.

Comment: @dfsq in my program the 2nd then executes even though the 1st promise is rejected although its working fine in your demo. I tired the same thing using return as mentioned by juco and it worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

One of the really great things about promises is that they can be chained like this:

```
function1 (){
  return service1.isDbExist.then(function(exists){
    if(!exists) return service1.createDB()
  })
  .then(function() {
    return service1.getData('some', 'args')
  });
}
```

Remember that the `.then` will receive the result of the previous function, like the exists would be a boolean. `function1` will also return a promise and this promise will return the resolved/rejected promise from `service1.getData`.