# How to execute Async forEach over a List and on each item, execute sync task

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous

I have a matter which I can not find a suitable solution.

In Angular.js, I have a "List of List" where the first top list contains a second list of items, where each item need to run a $http GET.

I want this:

Task 10 - Task 11 - Task 12 -->  *run in parallel*
| 
Task 20 -->  *run in parallel after Task 1- are finished*
|
Task 30 - Task 31 -->  *run in parallel after Task 2- are finished*

I tried to use angular.forEach inside angular.forEach but all the tasks are run in parallel.

I don't know how to handle this.

Comment: asynchronous is **not** parallel. But you are right that they don't run in sync. To do that you would want to resolve them with `$q.all( list_of_promises )`, which can accept a list of your promises that you can populate in a for loop. For links/dependancies - just chain then within each other's resolve

Comment: but as my first list is built dynamically, I don't know how to chains the items ?

Comment: [chain promises*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31366323/chain-multiple-promises-in-angularjs?rq=1)

Comment: I found my way with this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28983424/make-angular-foreach-wait-for-promise-after-going-to-next-object Thanks for showing me the right way, I didn't know I could dynamically chains promises !!